# bio-compatible thermoset resin

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, safety

I am looking for something rather odd and specific.

I need a chemical resin that is liquid up to 250 deg. F,  Is a thermoset (it cures at temperatures above 250 F), and is biocompatible in that if the resin is consumed or enters the blood stream it is not toxic to humans in quantities up to 2 cm^3.  If anyone has insight it would be extremely helpful!